# minimum order quantity category based

Tags: category, price, quantity

I want to set minimum order quantity (moq) based on category.

Say a product name A in catgeory 1 and category 2:

I want to set **moq to be 2 for category 1** and **moq to be 5 for category 2** based on which category user is browser.

Please guide me way to do this I need help to start off, i am new to Magento and need help in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to make some reasonment for what you are asking.

First of all: **products are not necessarily added to cart by navigating a category**; some examples are:

- I add a product to cart from a search result
- I add a product to cart by performing a re-order
- I update a product quantity of a product in a saved cart

these are only a few that come in my mind but there are more.

So first of all you have to define a **strategy**, that is what to do in these cases and what (if any) minimum quantity you will allow to be added to cart.

So said, let's try to understand how product **minimum quantity check** is performed.

You can start from `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item::setQty()` method which is called when an item is added to cart.

That method dispatches a `sales_quote_item_qty_set_after` event which is observed by `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::checkQuoteItemQty()` method;

it's a very long method which in turn delegates the minimum allowed quantity check to `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::checkQuoteItemQty()` method;

this in turn delegates to `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Stock_Item::getMinSaleQty()` that is where the chain ends up.

I encourage you to study that code to understand what happens under the hood.

As you can guess, you can observe the `sales_quote_item_qty_set_after` event to inject your logic through a custom module.

Pay attention to add a dependency to `Mage_CatalogInventory` module in your module activation XML file under `{magento_root}/app/etc/modules`; this is necessary in order for your observer to be called after `Mage_CatalogInventory_Model_Observer::checkQuoteItemQty()`.

At this point you can check whether you are adding a product from a specific category; to do that, simply invoke `Mage::helper('catalog')->getCategory()` which will return a `Mage_Catalog_Model_Category` object if you are adding a product to cart from a category (or from a product page reached by navigating a category), `null` otherwise.

In case of `null` you have to apply the strategy I mentioned at the beginning.

Hope it helps.

Comment: hey bro can u help me as paid support as i am new here

Comment: Sorry, I can't.

Comment: ok np , but can u give me hint to do that which oberserver to use like that

Comment: you have to implement your own observer, binding it to the event I pointed out; if you are not a Magento programmer you can't do that on your own;

Comment: i am newbie will try and ping u if needed